# pyspark map with user defined function not working when written outside script

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am using python 2.7 with pyspark,

I use a user defined function and it works well when i use it like this

```
def func(x):
    pass 

RDD.map(lambda x:func(x))
```

but when I create the function inside another script called utils and use

```
from utils import func as func 
RDD.map(lambda x:func(x))
```

I get an error

> ImportError: No module named utils

how can i import a function from a user defined module and use it with RDD map?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In command line:

```
spark-submit --py-files utils.py ...
```

Or in script:

```
sc.addPyFile('file:///path/to/utils.py')
```

Comment: Please don't forget to add some text explaining your answer - why it works and how it solves the original problem

Comment: how do you integrate this inside a python script using spark context?

Comment: ```SparkContext().getConf().set('pyfiles',['file:///path/to/utils.py'])
```